# Magento - Newsletter subscribe new field not saving

Tags: magento, observers

I am trying to add a new field (subscriber_type) to the newsletter subscribe form. I have setup my observer and it is working and firing correctly (newsletter_subscriber_save_before):

```
<?php
class Mynamespace_Enhancednewsletter_Model_Observer {
    public function saveBefore($observer){
        $subscriber = $observer->getEvent()->getSubscriber();
        $type = Mage::app()->getRequest()->getParam('type'); // this contains my new data correctly
        $subscriber->setSubscriberType($type);
        return $this;
    }
}
```

I have also added the field to the db.
The above code adds the new subscriber but doesn't add the subscriber_type.

Can anyone see where I'm going wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Man this one was frustrating..but the answer was so simple:

Magento caches table descriptions so make sure you clear your cache after adding a new field to the db.

Thanks to MJA for the answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/10550476/491055